# keep column as input in aggregate function output in R

Tags: r, csv, aggregate, aggregate-functions

I am witing a function a to calculate mean of column values with respect to other two columns values, but when called the function and it gives output with changed column names. I want to keep same column as input file

this a function code in which i want to calculate mean of column `total_pause_time` with respect to column `employee_is` and `group_id` for input file `my_data`
I have represent total_pause_time as col_name1 in function and similarly `employee_id` as `col_name2` and `group_id` as `col_name3`. In output I am getting column names as `col_name1`, `col_name2`, `col_name3` instead of `total_pause_time`,`employee_id` and `group_id`.

```
{
  avg <- aggregate(col_name1~col_name2+col_name3,input_file,FUN="mean")
  write.csv(avg, file = "average.csv")
 }

avg(my_data$total_pause_time,my_data$employee_id,my_data$group_id,my_data)
```

Comment: I guess you need `aggregate(data['total-pause_time'], data[c('employee_id', 'group_id']), FUN = mean)`

Comment: The LHS of formulas are going to be the column values. RHS the row indices. And if you're going to use the formula method then just use a data argument and column names.

Answer (score 0):

If we need a function, use the `[` instead of `$` to subset the columns

```
avg <- function(col_name1, col_name2, col_name3){
  aggregate(data[col_name1], data[c(col_name2,col_name3)],  FUN = mean)
}

avg("total_pause_time", "employee_id", "group_id")
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
data <- data.frame(employee_id = rep(1:3, each = 3),
                    group_id = sample(1:3, 9, replace=TRUE), 
                    total_pause_time = sample(1:5, 9, replace=TRUE))
```